# Its possible to convert a Java Jax-ws app to rest?

Tags: java, spring, rest, web-services

Im dealing with this situation. I have a Jax-ws app running several services and I need to expose this services in a REST app. How I can convert it? Can I make a ""Proxy"" between the 2 apps? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

The unique approach I can think is create a JAX-RS application that consumes your JAX-WS services, and you use it like a proxy while you migrate each service to your new JAX-RS application.